# Schema.describeSObjects() returns incorrect values

Tags: apex, security

When I use `Schema.describeSObjects()` the result always returns `isDeletable=TRUE`, even though the current user doesn't have DELETE permission on an sObject; however if `Schema.sObjectType.<<sObject>>` is used, then it returns expected result i.e. `isDeletable=FALSE`.

Above observation was found for `isCreateable` flag as well!

Comment: I would recommend simply not using it because it's far slower than single describe calls for now.

Comment: I've a requirement where I need to pass the sObject name dynamically to retrieve Access permissions for any sObject(a generic method), cannot harcode like Schema.sObjectType.Account etc.

Comment: See [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/219010) for a dynamic alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the describe call is returning incorrect values, that's a bug that definitely needs to be fixed. I will send a short message to some people I know on the Salesforce side, but you should definitely log a case so they can file a bug for this.

Answer (score 1):

In case any one else ends up here - this was a bug, and was fixed in Winter 19 - but it was also a versioned change, so unless you update your API version in the class, it is still not going to work!

> Note that while this issue is fixed in WInter '19, the change has been
> versioned to avoid breaking previously functional code. It is strongly
> advised that you upgrade your Apex class API version to opt-in to the
> corrected behavior.

[Link](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008djFAAQ&title=sobjecttype-getdescribe-or-schema-describesobjects-do-not-correctly-reflect-the-isaccessible-iscreateable-isdeletable-isundeletable-isupdateab) to KI: