# Get the type (data type) of a field in apex

Tags: apex

I need to get the type (or data type) of a field (like if it is a date or integer for example) in apex.

I only have the name (api) of the object and the name of the field.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Type.forname with a describe call and fieldmap get will do it

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The other two are right that you can use `Schema.getGlobalDescribe()`, but it is notoriously slow. Make sure that you either cache the global describe into a static variable so that you only call `Schema.getGlobalDescribe()` once per transaction, or consider the method from this question: [Why is Schema.describeSObjects(types) Slower Than Schema.getGlobalDescribe()?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/218982/why-is-schema-describesobjectstypes-slower-than-schema-getglobaldescribe)

Which would look like this for your case:

```
String objectName = 'Account';
String fieldName = 'Name';

SObjectType r = ((SObject)(Type.forName('Schema.'+objectName).newInstance())).getSObjectType();
DescribeSObjectResult d = r.getDescribe();
System.debug(d.fields
        .getMap()
        .get(fieldName)
        .getDescribe()
        .getType());
```

Comment: I can't compile your  code sample, I got an error 'Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void SObject(Object)' at the first line

Comment: Sorry about that, I lost a closing bracket somewhere along the line when I was formatting the code. I've updated my answers and it should work now.

Comment: thanks, I will use your answer since it's more effective so !

Comment: Thx for expanding on my comment +1

Answer (score 7):

depends on what you want to get: [SOAPType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_enum_Schema_SOAPType.htm) or [DisplayType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_enum_Schema_DisplayType.htm)

```
String objectName = 'Opportunity';
String fieldName =  'AccountId';

Schema.DisplayType f = Schema.getGlobalDescribe() // or Schema.SOAPType
    .get(objectName)
    .getDescribe()
    .fields
    .getMap()
    .get(fieldName)
    .getDescribe()
    .getType(); // or getSOAPType()
System.debug(f);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit irritating in SF (from my point of view). But you can do it like this:

```
String objType=’YourObject’;
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
Schema.SObjectType leadSchema = schemaMap.get(objType);
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = leadSchema.getDescribe().fields.getMap();

for (String fieldName: fieldMap.keySet()) {
  Schema.DisplayType fielddataType = fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getType();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Important to note that while the other answers here will do what you're looking to do, there is a subtle gotcha I discovered while making a method to grab any phone numbers off of a record on a standard controller:

```
public String getSObjectPhoneFields() {

    SObject sObj = scon.getRecord();

    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objectDescribe = sObj.getSObjectType().getDescribe();

    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fields = objectDescribe.fields.getMap();
    Map<String, Object> result = new Map<String, Object>();

    for(String fieldName : fields.keySet()) {
        Schema.SObjectField field = fields.get(fieldName);
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldDescribe = field.getDescribe();
        if(fieldDescribe.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Phone) {
            result.put(fieldDescribe.getLabel(), sObj.get(field));
        }
    }

    return JSON.Serialize(result);        
}
```

As it turns out, Schema.DisplayType is *not* the same as the DATA TYPE column in the object manager. This manifested as (in my case) the Fax number on the Contact type being handed in as a phone number, despite it's DATA TYPE being Fax. This is because a Fax is *displayed* (see: Schema.*Display*Type) as a phone number, despite it being a different *data* type.

I wasn't able to find how to access the data type. It doesn't appear to be available through the API.

Answer (score 1):

Even more simple now!

```
public String getFieldDataType(String objectName, String fieldName){
    return [SELECT DataType 
            FROM FieldDefinition 
            WHERE EntityDefinitionId=:objectName AND QualifiedApiName=:fieldName 
            LIMIT 1].DataType;
}
```

Comment: I'll be careful with this approach as it will count towards your SOQL Governor Limits.