# Export several objects picklist details into CSV file using apex

Tags: apex, picklist, schema

**Context**

We need to export picklist label and API values for several objects, in a csv file using apex.

Several posts exist on this subject but the objective is to export picklist values for several objects at once, not only for a single object.

This question aims to be a knowledge sharing post and provides a working script how this requirement can be achieved

Comment: May I know the reason of the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample apex code to achieve this requirement.

Hope this helps someone looking to achieve something similar

```
Set<String> setObjects = new Set<String>{'Account','Contact'}; //list your objects' API name including custom object, note that too many objects can cause Apex CPU limit exceeded
String generatedCSVFile ='Object;FieldName;Label;APIName'+ '\n';

for (String apiname: setObjects ){
String fileRow = '';
    String objectName = apiname;
    system.debug(objectName );

    SObjectType r = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName) ;
    DescribeSObjectResult d = r.getDescribe();
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> mapfields = d.fields.getMap();

    for(String fieldn : mapfields.keyset()){
        String fieldName =fieldn ;
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = mapfields.get(fieldn).getDescribe();
        if(fieldResult.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.PICKLIST){

           List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
           for( Schema.PicklistEntry pickListVal : ple){
              //System.debug(pickListVal.getLabel() +' '+pickListVal.getValue());
              fileRow = '';
              //change csv delimiter accordingly
              fileRow = fileRow +';'+ objectName; 
              fileRow = fileRow +';'+ fieldName;
              fileRow = fileRow +';'+ pickListVal.getLabel();
              fileRow = fileRow +';'+ pickListVal.getValue();
              fileRow = fileRow.replaceFirst(';','');
              generatedCSVFile = generatedCSVFile + fileRow + '\n';
           }
        }
    }

}

system.debug(generatedCSVFile );

ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
cv.firstPublishLocationId= UserInfo.getUserId();
cv.Title = 'PicklistExtract'; 
cv.pathOnClient = 'PicklistExtract.csv'; 
cv.VersionData = Blob.valueOf(generatedCSVFile); //file data
insert cv; //file is saved current user's my files
```

This answer is inspired and derived by related answers on these posts, thanks to the contributors

[How to dynamically query any Field's Picklist values using Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/381332)

[Get the type (data type) of a field in apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/223330)