# How to verify in APEX if the organization has notes enabled?

Tags: apex, notes

To be more specific, I am talking about the 'new' notes introduced with the Summer '15 release [link](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_sales_notes_take_rich_text_notes.htm)

Would it be enough to verify if `ContentNote` is available by using:

```
Boolean isNotesEnabled = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().containsKey('ContentNote')
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, or you can save the cost of a [global describe](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/219010) using Type.forName:

```
Boolean isNewNotesEnabled = Type.forName('Schema.ContentNote') != null;
```