# How to get List of Custom fields using dynamic apex

Tags: apex

I am trying to get list of custom fields of an object using dynamic apex

Comment: Please provide some more details on the requirement.
What blocked you doing so?
What have you tried yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying salesforcesas's answer a bit, done for performance (see sfdcfox's answer to [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/218982/why-is-schema-describesobjectstypes-slower-than-schema-getglobaldescribe)) and clean API usage:

```
public static List<String> getCustomFields(String apiName) {
    SObjectType objType = ((SObject) (Type.forName('Schema.' + apiName).newInstance())).getSObjectType();
    Map<String, SObjectField> fieldsByName = objType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    List<String> customFields = new List<String>();

    for (SObjectField field : fieldsByName.values()) {
        if (field.getDescribe().isCustom()) {
            customFields.add(field.getDescribe().getName());
        }
    }

    System.debug('customFields => ' + customFields);

    return customFields;
}
```

Of course, you could change this to take an SObjectType or a DescribeSObjectResult and/or update the return to be a different type of collection or to be the SObjectField instances or DescribeFieldResult values as needed.

Comment: the condition:
`if (field.isCustom())` cause an error :
`Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void isCustom() from the type Schema.SObjectField`

it should be changed to:
`if (field.getDescribe().isCustom())`
to make it work properly

Comment: @gilwo thanks for the feedback. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you can get by below method:

```
public static Map<String,String> getCustomFields(String objName){
    Map<String,String> customFields = new Map<String,String>();
    SObjectType accountType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objName);
    Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> mfields = accountType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    for(String fld : mfields.keySet()){
        if(fld.contains('__c'))
            customFields.put(fld, mfields.get(fld).getDescribe().getName());
    }
    System.debug('customFields => '+customFields);
    return customFields;
}
```

Now you can pass object name to get all its custom fields:

```
poc.getCustomFields('Account'); // to get account custom fields
```