# Attempt to de-reference a null object when using alternative to getGlobalDescribe

Tags: error, sobject, null-pointer, sobjecttype, type

In the following code

```
String myString = 'Account'; 
SObjectType sObjType = ((SObject) Type.forName(myString).newInstance()).getSObjectType();
```

When myString = a object name does not exist i get a NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object.

Is there any way to check this before getting this error without using Schema.getGlobalDescribe() ?

[speed comparison between above and getXXDescribe methods](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/219010/71826)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is an invalid (or null) return on the [Type class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_type.htm) using `forName`.

You need to validate the return of `forName` before looking to cast into an [SObjectType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_SObjectType.htm)

```
String myString = 'InvalidClass'; 
Type classType = Type.forName(myString);

SObjectType sObjType;

if (classType != null) {
    sObjType = ((SObject) classType.newInstance()).getSObjectType();
}
```

Comment: i see, thank you !

Comment: it is also recommended to use `Type.forName(null, className)`  to make sure, that code will work properly on namespaced orgs. First Param is the name of the namespace