# Provide Read access to all Objects and their fields in my entire ORG

Tags: apex, batch, metadata-api, error

I have written the below script in order to provide Read permission on all my Objects and their fields.
I have managed Objects, standard and custom objects on the Org. I am maintaining all Objects in custom settings and querying from there

While running the class, I am running into multiple errors as I am dealing with all objects.
errors are:

```
Invalid field permission field name Account field Account.billingstatecode
21:35:27.882 (5883191351)|USER_DEBUG|[84]|DEBUG|err mess Permission Read All Asset depends on permission(s): Read All Account
21:35:27.882 (5883212594)|USER_DEBUG|[84]|DEBUG|err mess Permission Read Asset depends on permission(s): Read Account
21:35:27.882 (5883227064)|USER_DEBUG|[84]|DEBUG|err mess Permission Read All Asset depends on permission(s): Read All Account
21:35:27.882 (5883240569)|USER_DEBUG|[84]|DEBUG|err mess Permission Read Asset depends on permission(s): Read Account
21:35:27.882 (5883256868)|USER_DEBUG|[84]|DEBUG|err mess Permission Read All AuthorizationFormDataUse depends on permission(s): Read All DataUsePurpose
21:35:27.882 (5883275544)|USER_DEBUG|[84]|DEBUG|err mess Permission Read AuthorizationFormDataUse depends on permission(s): Read DataUsePurpose
21:35:27.882 (5883294478)|USER_DEBUG|[84]|DEBUG|err mess Permission Read All AuthorizationFormDataUse depends on permission(s): Read All DataUsePurpose
21:35:27.882 (5883313772)|USER_DEBUG|[84]|DEBUG|err mess Permission Read AuthorizationFormDataUse depends on permission(s): Read DataUsePurpose
21:35:27.882 (5883348945)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|AssignReadPermissionsBatch
```

I am not sure How many more errors I will encounter. Could someone inspect my code and correct something if needed.

```
public class AssignReadPermissionsBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.AllowsCallouts {
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        // collect the batches of records or objects to be passed to execute
       // String query='SELECT SObjectType From ObjectPermissions';
         String query = 'Select Name from DatalakeObjects__c';
         return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<DatalakeObjects__c> records){
        // process each batch of records
         
        List<MetadataService.PermissionSetObjectPermissions> objPermissions = new List<MetadataService.PermissionSetObjectPermissions>();
        List<MetadataService.PermissionSetFieldPermissions> fldPermissions = new List<MetadataService.PermissionSetFieldPermissions>();
        
        for (DatalakeObjects__c obj:records){
            
            //DescribeSObjectResult objDef = obj.getDescribe();
            MetadataService.PermissionSetObjectPermissions objPrmsn = new MetadataService.PermissionSetObjectPermissions();
            objPrmsn.object_x = obj.Name;
           // objPrmsn.allowRead = true;
            objPrmsn.allowCreate = false;
            objPrmsn.allowDelete = false;
            objPrmsn.allowEdit = false;
            objPrmsn.allowRead = true;
            objPrmsn.viewAllRecords = true;
            objPrmsn.modifyAllRecords = false;
            objPermissions.add(objPrmsn);
            //Map<String, SObjectField> fields = objDef.fields.getMap();
            //Set<String> fieldSet = fields.keySet();
            //List <String> fieldLst = Utilities.getFields(obj.Name);
            System.debug('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'+obj.Name);
            SObjectType objToken = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(obj.Name);
            
            DescribeSObjectResult objDef = objToken.getDescribe();
            Map<String, SObjectField> fields = objDef.fields.getMap(); 
             
            Set<String> fieldSet = fields.keySet();

            for(String fldName:fieldSet){
                SObjectField fieldToken = fields.get(fldName);
                DescribeFieldResult selectedField = fieldToken.getDescribe();
                if(selectedField.isPermissionable() && selectedField.isAccessible()){
                MetadataService.PermissionSetFieldPermissions fldPrmsn = new MetadataService.PermissionSetFieldPermissions();
                //fldPrmsn.field = selectedField.getName();
                fldPrmsn.field = obj.Name+'.'+fldName;
                fldPrmsn.readable = true;
                fldPrmsn.editable = false;
                fldPermissions.add(fldPrmsn);
                // fieldList.add(selectedField.getName());
                }
            }
            
        }//end of upper for
        MetadataService.PermissionSet ps = new MetadataService.PermissionSet();
        ps.fullName = 'Assign_ReadOnly';
        ps.label = 'AssignReadOnly_3';
        ps.objectPermissions = objPermissions;
        ps.fieldPermissions = fldPermissions;
        ps.hasActivationRequired = false;
        
        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
        service.timeout_x = 60000;
        service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
        service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
        
         MetadataService.Metadata[] mtDataList = new List<MetadataService.Metadata>();
         mtDataList.add(ps);
        
             
        List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results;
        if(!System.Test.isRunningTest()){
            results = service.createMetadata(mtDataList);
        }else {
            results = new List<MetadataService.SaveResult>();
            results[0].success = false;
            MetadataService.Error err = new MetadataService.Error();
            err.message = 'test';
            List<MetadataService.Error> errList = new List<MetadataService.Error>{err};
                results[0].errors = errList;
        }
        for(MetadataService.SaveResult res: results){
            System.debug(res.success);
            if(res.errors != null){
                for(MetadataService.Error err:res.errors){
                    System.debug('err mess '+err.message);
                }
                
            }
        }
    
        
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        // execute any post-processing operations
    }
}
```

Edited to Queuable

```
public class ReadPermissionsBatch implements Queueable,Database.AllowsCallouts {
    
    List<DatalakeObjects__c> lakeLst = new  List<DatalakeObjects__c>();
     public ReadPermissionsBatch(){
          lakeLst = [Select Name from DatalakeObjects__c];
    }
   

    public void execute(QueueableContext context){
        // process each batch of records
       // List<DatalakeObjects__c> lakeLst = [Select Name from DatalakeObjects__c];
        List<MetadataService.PermissionSetObjectPermissions> objPermissions = new List<MetadataService.PermissionSetObjectPermissions>();
        List<MetadataService.PermissionSetFieldPermissions> fldPermissions = new List<MetadataService.PermissionSetFieldPermissions>();
        
        for (DatalakeObjects__c obj:lakeLst){
            
            //DescribeSObjectResult objDef = obj.getDescribe();
            MetadataService.PermissionSetObjectPermissions objPrmsn = new MetadataService.PermissionSetObjectPermissions();
            objPrmsn.object_x = obj.Name;
           // objPrmsn.allowRead = true;
            objPrmsn.allowCreate = false;
            objPrmsn.allowDelete = false;
            objPrmsn.allowEdit = false;
            objPrmsn.allowRead = true;
            objPrmsn.viewAllRecords = true;
            objPrmsn.modifyAllRecords = false;
            objPermissions.add(objPrmsn);
            //Map<String, SObjectField> fields = objDef.fields.getMap();
            //Set<String> fieldSet = fields.keySet();
            //List <String> fieldLst = Utilities.getFields(obj.Name);
          
            SObjectType objToken = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(obj.Name);
            
            DescribeSObjectResult objDef = objToken.getDescribe();
            Map<String, SObjectField> fields = objDef.fields.getMap(); 
             
            Set<String> fieldSet = fields.keySet();

            for(String fldName:fieldSet){
                SObjectField fieldToken = fields.get(fldName);
                DescribeFieldResult selectedField = fieldToken.getDescribe();
                if(selectedField.isPermissionable() && selectedField.isAccessible()){
                MetadataService.PermissionSetFieldPermissions fldPrmsn = new MetadataService.PermissionSetFieldPermissions();
                //fldPrmsn.field = selectedField.getName();
                fldPrmsn.field = obj.Name+'.'+fldName;
                fldPrmsn.readable = true;
                fldPrmsn.editable = false;
                fldPermissions.add(fldPrmsn);
                // fieldList.add(selectedField.getName());
                }
            }
            
        }//end of upper for
        MetadataService.PermissionSet ps = new MetadataService.PermissionSet();
        ps.fullName = 'Assign_ReadOnly';
        ps.label = 'AssignReadOnly_3';
        ps.objectPermissions = objPermissions;
        ps.fieldPermissions = fldPermissions;
        ps.hasActivationRequired = false;
        
        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
        service.timeout_x = 60000;
        service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
        service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
        
         MetadataService.Metadata[] mtDataList = new List<MetadataService.Metadata>();
         mtDataList.add(ps);
        
             
        List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results;
        if(!System.Test.isRunningTest()){
            results = service.createMetadata(mtDataList);
        }else {
            results = new List<MetadataService.SaveResult>();
            results[0].success = false;
            MetadataService.Error err = new MetadataService.Error();
            err.message = 'test';
            List<MetadataService.Error> errList = new List<MetadataService.Error>{err};
                results[0].errors = errList;
        }
        for(MetadataService.SaveResult res: results){
            System.debug(res.success);
            if(res.errors != null){
                for(MetadataService.Error err:res.errors){
                    System.debug('err mess '+err.message);
                }
                
            }
        }
    
        
    }
    

}
```

Comment: As the errors state, you did not provide View All Data for Account, DataUsePurpose, etc. You need to add more custom setting records.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't do this in a batch, as you can't control dependencies, which may also be a cause of the problem. This probably should be a Queueable instead of Batchable.

Comment: @sfdcfox- Thank you for the recommendation, Now with Queuable implementation all the dependency errors are gone. I am facing Attempt to dereference a null pointer exception on line DescribeSObjectResult objDef = objToken.getDescribe(); Any help is appreciated- I have updated Queuable code above for reference

Comment: @sfdcfox- I am able to address all errors, But using Queuable Apex, I am running in to CPU Time out error as We have huge metadata in form of objects and fields

Comment: You'd have to profile it to figure out where the CPU time is going, but the largest offender is probably calling Schema.getGlobalDescribe() repeatedly. You might try using [my solution](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/218982/2984) for a faster describe call.