# Dynamically get object info

Tags: dynamic, schema

I see so many examples like below; however, I want to be able to pass a string that holds 'Account' or custom object name for example.  The examples I see on SF are hard coding Account.

The reason I need this is because I have a table that users could enter any table name in that they want to get get data from within my code so I cannot possibly know what tables a person has in their org, they do!

```
//I need something like
String myObjectName = 'Account';
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult d = myObjectName.sObjectType.getDescribe();

//FROM SF Examples
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult d = Account.sObjectType.getDescribe();
Map<String, Schema.FieldSet> FSMap = d.fieldSets.getMap();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass objectname as a paramter also.

please see official documentation.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_describeSObject.htm

Comment: Until/unless they fix [this issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/218982/2984), I'd avoid intentionally using DescribeSObjects more than necessary.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox  for this information.

Comment: Thank you all for the support.  They are provide the need I wanted.  You guys rock!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
String myObjectName = 'Account';
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult d = ((sObject)Type.forName('Schema',myObjectName).newInstance()).getSObjectType().getDescribe();
```

Unlike using `Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(myObjectName)`, this code runs in about a millisecond instead of hundreds or thousands of milliseconds.

This trick is also faster than using describeSObjects, as discussed [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/218982/2984).

Comment: Now I have a similiar issue where I need to supply the field name dynamically as a string to get the field attributes, like Email field type, etc.  But SF always shows hard coded stuff when I try to search on their site.   Where the example below I don't want to hard code "Account" I want to pass "Account" to function as a string, for example.      Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr = Schema.SObjectType.Account.fields.Name;

Comment: @TomB From your DescribeResult, check out fields.getMap(). It returns a `Map<String, sObjectField>` that you can check to get all the fields for an object, and the sObjectField token can get you more details, like the type of field, maximum length, etc.

Comment: I am having trouble finding good solid examples on schema stuff to be honest.  I find snippets outside Saleforce's Apex Reference guide for the schema stuff.  I'll try to figure out a way to interate over that map.  I did prior to my second question see the fields listing in that map via debug, so if I follow you correctly, I should be able to iterate over that map to pull things out that I want to compare to.  Hoping I am on the right track.  Thank you.

Comment: @TomB yes, you can use fields.getMap().values() if you want to work with the tokens directly, or a combination of fields.getMap().keySet() and then get the tokens from the string values, whichever you think would work best for you.