# Check field is updatable

Tags: apex, sobject, schema

I have object and field name, but don't understand how to check if that field `isUpdatable`. It gives me the error:

> Variable does not exist: fields

```
SObjectType objectType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account'); 
objectType.fields.getMap().get('Name').getDescribe().isUpdateable();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `getDescribe()` for `objectType`

```
SObjectType objectType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account'); 
objectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().get('Name').getDescribe().isUpdateable();
```

---

Also pay attention, that `Schema.getGlobalDescribe()` is an expensive call in terms of server resource, so it is better to cache first invokation of it. [Why is Schema.describeSObjects(types) Slower Than Schema.getGlobalDescribe()?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/218982/why-is-schema-describesobjectstypes-slower-than-schema-getglobaldescribe)

if you don't want to cache it, use `Type.forName`

```
SObjectType objectType = ((SObject)Type.forName('Schema', 'Account').newInstance()).getSObjectType();
objectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().get('Name').getDescribe().isUpdateable();
```

Comment: Thanks, i was searching for that since previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't *think* you are using the right class, at least I've not done it that way before. Here's an quick, inelegant working alternative.

```
List<String> objNames = new List<String>{'Account'};
List<Schema.DescribeSobjectResult> dors = Schema.describeSObjects(objNames);
Schema.DescribeSobjectResult dor = dors[0];
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap =  dor.fields.getMap();
system.debug(fieldMap.get('Name').getDescribe().isUpdateable());
```